# Finding out what Javascript will run and when

Tags: javascript

What's the best way of finding out what Javascript will run and when? I've outgrown placing functions inside setTimeouts to delay running code to when I *think* the dependencies have already loaded, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not interested in putting the code that needs those calls in the `onload` event handler (will be invoked when all resources have been loaded), probably because you've got too many resources to load, or have some user behavior dependant on those resources, which might be triggered before it is loaded.

You might be interested in this resource: [Dynamic resource management in JavaScript](http://blog.gorges.us/2009/04/dynamic-resource-management-in-javascript/). There's an script through which you can load resources, and specify function callbacks to be invoked when the resource is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Would [jQuery's document ready method](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) solve your problems?

Comment: I think the OP wants to find out in his code if a certain resource has been already loaded.

Comment: it would if the code just had to load once, but i've got all sorts of onclicks and event listeners happening in there. i had thought of creating a flowchart diagram detailing the order in which the functions are called but i wonder if there is an easier way to understand it.